# Artinian iff finite dimensional

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

Let $F$ be a field and $M$ a finitely generated $F[x]$-module. Show that $M$ is Artinian iff the dimension of $M$ over $F$ is finite.

Thoughts so far: For the backward direction, I assume for the contrapositive that $M$ is not Artinian, giving me a strictly decreasing chain of modules. Then I can form a infinite set of linearly independent elements in $M$ over $F$ by picking an element from each module in the chain that doesn't belong to the proceeding module in the chain. Does this reasoning make sense for this direction of double implication?

For the other direction, I'm not sure how to begin. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One direction follows from the fact that a finite dimensional vector space over $F$ is artinian as $F$-module (chains of subspaces are finite).

Thus, an $F[x]$-module that's finite dimensional as $F$-vector space is artinian. This is true for modules $M$ over any $F$-algebra, because submodules are in particular subspaces.

The converse uses a particular property of $F[x]$ (it's not generally true that an artinian module over an $F$-algebra is necessarily finite dimensional).

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over $F[x]$ and suppose $M$ is artinian. It's not restrictive to assume that $M$ is singly generated (why?), so let $mF[x]=M$. Then $F[x]/\!\operatorname{Ann}(m)\cong M$ is artinian.

In particular, $\operatorname{Ann}(m)$ is the ideal generated by nonzero polynomial (why?). Thus $F[x]/\!\operatorname{Ann}(m)$ is finite dimensional as vector space over $F$.

Notes

1. $\operatorname{Ann}(m)=\{f\in F[x]:mf=0\}$ is the annihilator of $m$.
2. The structure theorem is not needed.

Comment: Your "it's not restrictive to assume..." hides most of the interesting action :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez A direct sum of artinian modules is artinian; submodules and quotient modules of artinian modules are artinian: it's basic knowledge, isn't it?

Comment: So is the result we are proving. It is a matter of adjusting what we say to the audience we have. We are not writing for Inventiones :-)

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Sorry, but I find your argument too long and confusing. A finitely generated module is artinian if and only if all of its cyclic submodules are artinian and this is true over *any* ring.

Comment: That statement, while true, is rather orthogonal to the matter at hand, since it is not true that a module is finite dimensional iff its cyclic submodules are.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez *Finitely generated*

Comment: At that point, your argument becomes exactly mine, with the only difference that you did not spell it out :-)

Comment: @egreg I'm working my way through your answer, and I want to check if I understand: about your first 'why?', don't you need the structure theorem to get this conclusion? By the structure theorem, M is isomorphic to a sum of cyclic modules, and this sum is Artinian iff each summand is Artinian, so it suffices to show each summand has to be Artinian. Is this why it's not restrictive to assume M is singly generated?

Comment: @m.deslauriers If $M=x_1A+\dots+x_nA$ (where $A$ is the base ring), then $M$ is a homomorphic image of $x_1A\oplus\dots\oplus x_nA$, which is artinian if and only if each summand is artinian; a homomorphic image of an artinian module is artinian and so is every submodule. Thus a finitely generated module is artinian if and only if each of its cyclic submodule is artinian.

Comment: @egreg Thank you. Now, for your second 'why?', is this simply because Ann(m) is an ideal from F[x], a PID, hence it is principal, and its generating polynomial is nonzero because of Mariano's first point below? Or is there another way to see this?

Comment: @m.deslauriers If $\text{Ann}(m)=\{0\}$, then $mF[x]$ is isomorphic to $F[x]$ which is certainly not artinian: only fields are artinian, among the integral domains.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Every submodule of M is a vector subspace, so a chain of submodules is in particular a chain of subspaces. This observation leads to a direct proof that a finite dimensional module is artinian.

Let us prove the converse.

- First, if u is an element of M, then there exists a polynomial in the ring such that pu=0, for otherwise $\{x^iF[x]u:i\geq0\}$ is an infinite descending chain of submodules of M all contained in F[x]u.
- From this, it follows that the module M is a torsion module. Since it is finitely generated, we can choose a finite sequence m_1, ..., m_k of elements in  which generates it. There are short exact sequences $$0\to (m_1,\dots,m_i)/(m_1,...,m_{i-1})\to M/(m_1,...,m_{i-1})\to M/(m_1,\dots,m_i)\to0$$ of artinian finitely generated torsion modules. An easy induction using these shows that to show that M is finite dimensional it is enough to show that all the modules $(m_1,\dots,m_i)/(m_1,...,m_{i-1})$ are finite dimensional, and for this more generally we can show that *cyclic* torsion modules are finite dimensional.
- This is clear, since all such modules are of the form $F[x]/(p)$ for a nonzero polynomial $p$.

Comment: I did not say otherwise. But it gives it in a direct,  less tortuous way, and that was the point...

Comment: Sorry, I will spend a lot more time on the second part of the problem, but I'm confused about the first. Why is every sub-module of M a subspace, given that M isn't itself a vector space? Isn't M simply a module over a ring?

Comment: If you think that M isn't a vector space, then the question you asked above does not make any sense!

Comment: Since the ring F[x] contains F as a subring, every F[x]-module can be viewed as an F-module, that is, as an F-vector sapce. This is precisely why the question you asked makes sense.

Comment: Thank you for helping me sort that out to myself. I think my confusion came from viewing M as a module over F[x] and not realizing that each submodule of M over F[x] can also be viewed as a subspace over F.